# WCF Communication error occurs randomly and impossible to catch the reason why

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

I have an application that use WCF as communication interface. Some time, the client call the ServiceHost and got that error:

> This channel can no longer be used to send messages as the output session was auto-closed due to a server-initiated shutdown. Either disable auto-close by setting the DispatchRuntime.AutomaticInputSessionShutdown to false, or consider modifying the shutdown protocol with the remote server.

I am a little bit out of solution after 1 month of research.

I think that the serviceHost go an timeout and the exception isn't handled. That make my serviceHost close. So the message is not the dirrect cause of the problem and i have no idea how to debug or handle error from WCF ServiceHost

Comment: turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985225/dealing-with-wcf-service-restart-on-client-side) won't tell you WHY you're getting the exceptions server-side, but could at least help you deal with them gracefully.